# Error while calculating derivatives

Tags: derivatives

> $$y=\frac{1}{2x^3}$$

The correct way to calculate the derivative of this function is:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{x^3}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{-3}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot -3x^{-4}=- \frac{3}{2x^4}$$

But this is the way that I tried and I don't understand why it doesn't work:
$$y'=\frac{1'(2x^3)-(2x^3)'1}{(2x^3)^2}=\frac{-(2x^3)'}{(2x^3)^2}=\frac{-6x^2}{4x^6}=\frac{-6x}{4x^4}$$

Where is the mistake? Why is the second way incorrect?

Comment: The mistake is in  the last line.

Comment: The second method isn't incorrect. You have just made an algebraic mistake: last line $$\frac{-6x^2}{4x^6}=\frac{2x^2}{2x^2}\cdot\frac{-3}{2x^4}=-\frac{3}{2x^4}$$ as obtained previously.

Comment: $x^2/x^6\ne x/x^4$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, of all, you write in the first method that

\begin{align}
y' &= \frac 1 2 \cdot x^{-3} \\
y' &= \frac 1 2 \cdot -3 x^{-4}
\end{align}

You've mixed up $y$ and $y'$ in several lines. I point this out because this is a very common careless error that I see a lot of students make.

---

Secondly, you've simplified $x^2 / x^6$ incorrectly in your second method. It's $1/x^4$, not $x/x^4$. Now the answers agree.

Comment: I think OP is quoting several options in a multiple-choice problem.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I really don't think that makes sense here - there's an algebraic progression between the lines, and I'm pretty sure it's just improperly written work.

Comment: Oh, now that I read it one more time, I see you could be right.  OP should have written $y$ in the first two lines and $y'$ in the last two.

Answer (score 0):

In your last step you forgot to remove X from numerator it's y' =-6/4x*4 and simply 
 It to get same answer , rest it is correct

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math formulas.